# Azure DevOps REST API: Getting work item predecessors and successors

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How do I get a work item's list of predecessors and successors using the Azure DevOps REST API?

I've found the API to list the items from a query and then get individual item details from there, but how do I get the predecessors and successors for each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it with [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#workitemexpand) with the `$expand=relations` URL parameter;

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1&$expand=relations
```

In the results you will get `relations` section, there you will see the links, in each link there are `attributes` with `name`, the `name` is Child/Successor/Predecessor:

```
"relations":  [
                  {
                      "rel":  "System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Forward",
                      "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/test/7fcdafd5-b891-4fe5-b2fe-1234567/_apis/wit/workItems/65",
                      "attributes":  "@{isLocked=False; name=Successor}"
                  },
```

Comment: Gives `page not found`